# .htaccess mod_rewrite error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the htaccess in the public_html:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
Options -Multiviews
Options -Indexes
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api\\dispatch\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/.* api/dispatch.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Here is the code for the htaccess in public_html/sites/

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.webznap\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://webznap.com/sites/%1/ [L]
```

Here is the htaccess for public_html/sites/luis/

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 400 /page/error
ErrorDocument 401 /page/error
ErrorDocument 403 /page/error
ErrorDocument 404 /page/error
ErrorDocument 500 /page/error

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

There you go thank you for all your help prix i really appreciate it !

Comment: i dont want the url to change at all

Comment: okay so how do i make it map to example.com/sites/luis/ ? but keep the luis.example.com look ?

Comment: yes i have a wild card... so why is it not mapping to it correctly am i missing something in my htaccess ? it maps correctly up to sites/ but it wont grab the subdomain and make it map to that name after sites/ where the %1 is

Comment: well no this is what i want i will be more clear... i want the subdomain to point to a folder inside of sites/ so if the subdomain is luis it will point to sites/luis/ and if it is test it will point to sites/test/

Comment: so basically i want to rewrite example.com/sites/luis/ to luis.example.com

Comment: @Prix This exists example.com/sites/luis/ and when i go to luis.example.com it only rewrites me to the sites/ it does not include luis for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 400 /page/error
ErrorDocument 401 /page/error
ErrorDocument 403 /page/error
ErrorDocument 404 /page/error
ErrorDocument 500 /page/error

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.webznap\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /sites/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api\\dispatch\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/.* api/dispatch.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

SIDE NOTE: `public_html/sites/.htaccess` and `public_html/sites/dynamic_subdoamin/.htaccess` should be removed!

And make sure that:

```
anything_you_try.domain.com
```

Exists on:

```
anything_your_try.domain.com/sites/anything_your_try
```

Or it will fail.

---

What it does?

The first line catch the sub-domain name if any:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

This line makes sure the sub-domain is not www, ftp or mail:

```
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
```

This line verify is the URL path does not start with `/sites`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites [NC]
```

This line will internally redirect whatever the URL is:

```
RewriteRule ^ /sites/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

So if the URL was for example:

```
http://luis.domain.com/hello
```

It will show the content of:

```
http://luis.domain.com/sites/luis/hello
```

Without changing the URL.

Comment: okay so now it is rewriting to luis.exapmle.com/sites/luis/ which i do not want ... i want the url to stay the same and for it to map to example.com/sites/luis/ right now it is mapping as far as sites/ i need it to just add on luis at the end...

Comment: @user3546263 the above will not map it to `sites/luis` unless you put that on the URL. Make sure you erase your cache or use a different browser since you have been doing it wrong and it was redirecting, you may have been cached.

Comment: @user3546263 I've edited it with an extended explanation of what it does.

Comment: maybe im saying it wrong ? okay here is what i want and i am not trying to be rude. When i had my htaccess code in my original post it was working the way i wanted it to... but for some reason it was only going in one folder and i need it to go in one more folder... right now if i were to go to luis.example.com it will map it to example.com/sites/ but it will not change the url at all.. i need it to go to example.com/sites/luis/ without the url changeing

Comment: your code is changing the url... and i dont want that

Comment: @user3546263 and how it is changing the URL if there is nothing on it that would perform a URL change? It leads me to believe your main domain `virtualhost` is different than the sub-domain `virtualhost`.

Comment: well right now when i go to luis.example.com it changes it to example.com/sites/luis/ i dont know why but it is

Comment: @user3546263 and have you tried using a different browser than the one you have been used as it may have been cached(if you were using Internet Explore try using Firefox or Chrome and vice-verse)? also make sure you don't have other `.htaccess` on the sub-folders in questions `sites` and `sites/luis`

Comment: would you like the real url so you can see that it is redirecting ?

Comment: if you have no problem giving out the URL on a public community like this, I could check it yes.

Comment: @user3546263 by the way forgot to mention this early but the wildcard must be configured not only on the DNS but needs to also be configured on the web server have you done both steps?

Comment: this is my entire htaccess file

Comment: @user3546263 it shows me a hostmonster page which again leads me to believe you have a virtualhost issue.

Comment: i have an htaccess file in the sites directory

Comment: @user3546263 if you have an `.htaccess` on the folder `sites` it will cancel the rules from a previous `.htaccess`, this is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/jIuUoKN.jpg

Comment: Check it again i just edited the htaccess with your code for the sites directory and it redirects you ...

Comment: @Prix do you see how it redirects you and the url is messed up ?

Comment: @user3546263 what is your folder break down and where is the `.htaccess` at? is it something like `/home/your_account_name_here/public_html/sites/luis` and the `.htaccess` is at `/home/your_account_name_here/public_html/.htaccess` and there is no other `.htaccess` inside sites or luis?

Comment: there is a htaccess in the public_html , there is one in the sites directory and in the luis directory. but the htaccess in the root just  takes the .php off and so does the one inside of luis

Comment: @user3546263 yes please post it on your question [**by editing it**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23351364/edit) with the content of the 3 `.htaccess` and if possible in what folder they are with the full path removing any sensitivity information such as username.

Comment: @user3546263 see my edited answer, you will 1) delete the `.htaccess` from luis and sites folder and 2) update your main `.htaccess` with the content I have posted above. Note that on your sites `.htaccess` you had removed %1 from the URL at `http://web...` which is why it was redirecting or possible why. **Also please put a file inside `sites/luis` called `test.html` with the content `hey we are at the right place` or anything you feel like just so we can test it,** as I don't know how your PHP is and it could be possible redirecting things by itself.

Comment: its still redirecting the url, and it shouldnt have to look for the sites/luis/ because that should already be loaded in luis.webznap.com correct ? it should not look like luis.webznap.com/sites/luis/

Comment: it should be looking for `luis.webznap.com/sites/luis/` otherwise it will change the URL, that's why we have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites [NC]` which allows you to use that address internally without breaking it.

Comment: it should be looking for webznap.com/sites/luis/ cause i just basically wanted to change that to luis.webznap.com so if you go to webznap.com/sites/luis/ it will show the site

Comment: @user3546263 if you remove the subdomain rule, does it let you access `http://luis.webznap.com/sites/luis`?

Comment: @user3546263 ops actually there was mistake on the rule I have fixed it we don't need the domain name at all on the rule as its a internal redirect. Should have been `RewriteRule ^ /sites/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` all along.

Comment: okay now its saying that its not found on the server when really if you just go to webznap.com/sites/luis/ it finds it

Comment: @user3546263 that is without the subdomain rule or with the new rule?

Comment: @user3546263 OK great, now lets find where that sub-domain is at, is your hosting plan with cPanel? did you create the sub-domain on cPanel or what?

Comment: yea on cpanel and i have made a wildcard subdomain pointing to sites/

Comment: @user3546263 I see, now it explains it. so the sub-domain wildcard is on the sites folder correct?

Comment: IT WORKS !!! I CHANGED IT TO THE SITE PUBLIC_HTML AND NOW IT WORKS THANK YOU FOR EVERYTHING ! YOUR THE BEST !

Comment: @user3546263 aw ... I was going to post an update to the rules where you could use it on the sites folder but I guess it doesn't need anymore

Comment: I appreciate your patience and your time you are truely the best !

Comment: @user3546263 well glad its working now :) I knew it was `virtualhost` problem from the begin hahaha ;)

Comment: hahahah :) hey do you have an email or something ? i would like to stay in contact you seem like a cool guy/gal